# Library to filter out USB data transfers?

Tags: c#, usb, libusb

I would like to prevent malware for spreading itself to any USB devices that might connect to the system. For that I thought about an "firewall" approach based on executable names. E.g: only the process iexplorer.exe can write to a USB device, any other process is blocked.

The solution needs to work in W10 using .NET technologies.
I search on internet and I found USBFilter but only works in Linux.
https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity16/technical-sessions/presentation/tian

for windows, I found the library http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/  but I does not have filtering capabilities.

Does anyone know any way to achieve this goal?